# Converting date time values in "factor" format to a "date" format works not on the whole column, produces a

Tags: r, date, time, type-conversion

i have data from a temperature logger with 4 sensors for almos a week in 5 Minute intervals. The Logger software lets me export a .csv file of the data which has an id column a date column and the 4 sensor value columns.
The columns looks like this:

```
1,01.29.18 06:00:00 PM,8.120,9.608,8.941,9.608
2,01.29.18 06:05:00 PM,7.995,9.534,8.891,9.558
3,01.29.18 06:10:00 PM,7.920,9.460,8.841,9.682
4,01.29.18 06:15:00 PM,7.845,9.386,8.891,9.780
```

When read it in with `read.csv()` i get a data table an the date column is of class "factor".

I tried to run:

```
strptime(dach$Datum.Zeit..GMT.01.00, format = "%d.%m.%y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "CET")
```

and

```
as.POSIXct(dach$Datum.Zeit..GMT.01.00, format = "%d.%m.%y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "CET")
```

with and without the `tz`argument. R always prints the first 648 rows as `NA`the following rows are converted just fine.

Why is that and how can i overcome this?

Comment: Because you tell R that the day comes first and then the month - then R thinks "I don't know anything about month nr 29."

Comment: ... i am looking for almost 2 days at this data now... Yes it had to be `"%m.%d.%y %I:%M:%S %p"`. Thank you!